# Initializing *ngFor with a new Array()

Tags: angular, ngfor

Angular v5

My search component retrieves data from a service returning a search result promise. On page load my "searchResults" array is empty (= new Array()) until the search is called in page and the promise is returned.

*ngFor is throwing an error because the above mentioned "searchResults" is empty on page load. How do I circumvent this until the search results are populated?

Service:

```
getSearchResults(searchTerm: string, resourceType: string, pageSize: number = 9999, pageNumber: number = 1): Promise<object> {
const search = {
  Term: searchTerm,
  ResourceType: resourceType,
  PageSize: pageSize,
  PageNum: pageNumber,
  ModuleId: moduleId
};
const searchHeader = {headers: this.getHttpHeaders()};
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
  this.http.post(this.apiRoot, search, searchHeader).toPromise()
    .then(response => {
      resolve(JSON.parse(response['_body']));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
});
return promise;
}
```

Component:

```
submitSearch(): void {
this.siteSearchService.getSearchResults(this.searchString, this.selectedResourceType)
  .then(response => {
    let dto: DTO.SearchResults = <DTO.SearchResults>response;
    this.totalHits = dto.TotalHits;
    this.searchResults = dto.Results;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="searchResults" style="margin:25px;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 result-row" *ngFor="let result in searchResults">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
          <a href [href]="result.Url" target="_blank" class="search-result-link">
            <h3>{{result.Title}}</h3>
          </a>
          <p>{{result.Description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
          ToDo: Button
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you try : `<div class="row" *ngIf="totalHits > 0 && searchResults " style="margin:25px;">` ?

Comment: I did, unfortunately it doesnt work.
Still showing compile error: "[ERROR ->]*ngFor="let result in searchResults"

Comment: can you remove the `?` after `searchResults` in `ngFor` ?

Comment: Updated original post to include your recommendations, still receiving the same compile time error mentioned in my above comment though.

Comment: Try just `*ngIf="searchResults"` and as Mohammed says try removing ? at the end of searchResults

Comment: Srinivas, applied to original post. Compile error remains intact.
"[ERROR ->]*ngFor="let result in searchResults">"

Comment: i think it should be `*ngFor= "let result of searchResults"` not `*ngFor="let result in searchResults"`

Comment: Srinivas, THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with `*ngIf="searchResults"` and also in your code replace 
`*ngFor="let result in searchResults"` with `*ngFor="let result of searchResults"`

Hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 2):

My fix would be to use the `async` pipe. This will let Angular know to wait for the results to arrive before trying to loop with ngFor. I would turn `searchResults` into an observable that emits results at the end of each search.

In the view, emit an event each time the button is clicked:

```
<input #searchInput />
<button (click)="searchSubject.next(searchInput.value)">Search</button>
```

In the component class:

```
// Will emit each new search term when user clicks search button
searchSubject = new Subject<string>();

// Will trigger the search each time the searchSubject emits:
searchResults = searchSubject
                 .switchMap(term => this.siteSearchService.getSearchResults(term));
                 .map(response => response.Results)
                 .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Finally modify the template to use the pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of searchResults | async">
```

The [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) will subscribe to `searchResults` and start listening to the click event. Once your component is destroyed, Angular will unsubscribe for you.

Comment: awesome suggestions! Thanks a lot!